# A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I catch

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in
>   invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

I've installed JDK and set `JAVA_HOME`. Also I've added this statement to senv.conf:

```
AS_JAVA="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67"
```

But nothing changes. What do?

Comment: Double-check your java path. Are you running Windows?

Comment: Is that the only Java installation on your computer? If you're using Eclipse, have a look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) to tell the IDE which Java installation to use.

Comment: @keyser, yes, I'm running windows 8

Comment: @watery, no. I think JRE was installed before

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: @keyser, it's a servlet.

Comment: You could try compiling a simple java class manually to see if it's a glassfish problem or a local path problem.

Comment: Are you running a Tomcat standalone instance then? Even there, you can tell it which Java installation to use (it's somewhere in the Tomcat management window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Tony,  uninstall jdk1.70_67, and install jdk1.70_25  or jdk1.70_45 ,  there are problems  with jdk1.70_60  and upwards.

Comment: I've uninstalled JRE and reinstalled JDK after all.

Answer (score 1):

For me above solution solutions did not work so that's what I did :

***On AWS Linux Server***

In my path to glassFih :

your/path/to/glassfish4/glassfish/config

I added at the bottom of these two files :

- **asenv.bat** : set AS_JAVA=\usr\java\jdk1.8.0_141 (remplace with your java jdk version)
- **asenv.conf** : AS_JAVA="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_141"  (remplace with your java jdk version)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
JAVA_HOME = c:\my_app\java
```

I made it:

```
JAVA_HOME = c:\my_app\java\jdk
```

(adapt the path to your configuration)

In my case this was helpful.